# How to tell speakers that their English is terrible?

Tags: communication, feedback

I just had a lecture from someone who has been a senior scientist (and has completed a PhD, post-doc) at a hospital for already 15 years. So I'm assuming this person is experienced in giving talks in English. However, almost one out of three words was completely unintelligible because of a very strong Spanish accent where every word gets morphed into a Spanish-English hybrid word.

I spoke to two people after the lecture and they both said they couldn't follow along because of the strong accent. The questions after the talk were also not about the lecture but about the speaker's field. My impression is that the talk was a waste of time for the two dozen people present.

Now I wonder if the speaker is aware of this problem, my guess is no and as such I feel the need to bring this to the speaker's attention. If it was me I'd very much like to know that I have a problem communicating because I feel like a lack of communication skills can be a very serious barrier to being a good scientist but I don't know if she feels the same way.

My plan is to use an anonymous email address to send this feedback, sandwiched between two compliments to avoid coming off as a negative person.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66599/discussion-on-question-by-plumpie-how-to-tell-speakers-that-their-english-is-ter).

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/84372/14332) to a similar question would fit perfectly well here. One of my cleverest colleagues has an impenetrable accent. If this person has been successful despite their communication issues, it's probably worth your while for *you* to figure out what they have to say.

Comment: You don't. Don't speak, write more. Let all your works be presented on your website. You can edit it even after ages and are open to constructive comments from the viewers ;)

Comment: I am a bilingual speaker who has a horrible accent in my second language. I've been married to a native speaker for 8 years and lived in a town which primarily speaks it for 5. Nonetheless, my accent is horrible, and I am fully aware of it and have worked on it in many different ways. For some people, and for some language combinations, this is a very time consuming and difficult process. There were times when I just gave up for a while because it was too hard. Fortunately for me, my husband, his family, and our friends have all been very patient and understanding with me.

Comment: @stanri it sounds like you have good insight into the situation of the speaker. Given your perspective, what is your view about OP's question?

Comment: @DanRomik I didn't make an answer because there are already 12 of them, and they're mostly correct. The assumption that she isn't aware of this is most likely incorrect. I just wanted to convey how difficult this can be to fix. One of my best friends is a speech therapist and she works with clients for *years* to fix their speech. She has taught me exercises to improve my accent (like reading books out loud, with my husband, and having him correct my pronunciation and then listening to him read the same thing), and even with her professional help it's very slow going.

Comment: FWIW sometimes after three or four lectures you may start to intuitively understand and not even notice the heavy accent as you did at first.  In my experience both frequency and duration of exposure to any, er, "dialect", have an effect on one's ability to comprehend.  Although, depending on how severe it is, an hour or two a week may or may not be enough.  Perhaps you could watch some youtube videos of other people with similar speech patterns? (I think that really may have some effectiveness despite striking me as an almost silly thing to suggest)

Comment: Just tell them. I am going to guess that you are from the US; compared to other western cultures, American is unusually non-confrontative. In many other cultures giving constructive criticism is entirely OK, even if you don't spend half an hour making up fake praises first. (Making it clear that you are trying to help and not just being mean *is* a good idea though.) As a non-native speaker who has spent a lot of time stressing over whether I am being understood, honest feedback is quite helpful. Even more so if you can give some specifics (too silent, too fast etc).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This *might* be productive in a direct conversation, if you are able to establish rapport, and if you can steer the conversation in a productive direction.  You could start by asking her to clarify some key point you were interested in.  Stop her as soon as there's something you don't understand, and if necessary ask her to spell the word you don't understand.  The goal at this point is to succeed in communicating with each other.

If you are able to accomplish that, then you could say

> Thanks for clarifying that point. That is really interesting for me.  I didn't understand what you said on that point during the lecture -- to tell you the truth, I was only able to get the meaning of some of what you said, and that made it hard for me to follow the arc of the presentation.  I'm not very good at understanding <strike>nonstandard</strike> unfamiliar accents.  So I have to rely heavily on the visual with a lot of speakers.  Your slides about (topic B) helped me a lot, because they had a lot of detail.

That is a conclusion that helps the speaker move forward in a positive direction.

---

Additional notes.

Often one needs to crank up the belief in oneself in order to get through the PhD and other hurdles in academia.  This sometimes leads one to a slightly Aspergeresque attitude of "I can find the words I need to express myself; mission accomplished; I'm not interested in how well other people are understanding me."  Step one is to establish rapport.

Sometimes this rapport can result in the stronger English speaker having some influence over the other.  Sometimes it results in the stronger English speaker getting tuned into the other's speech patterns better, and perhaps also developing empathy for what has led the other to his or her current state of mediocre English.  This happened to me with respect to my advisor.  For the most part I'm one of those people who finds horrible English, or horrible French, or horrible Spanish, excruciating, like chalk going the wrong way on a blackboard; and it continues to torment me later like a stuck song (ear worm).  Once my empathy with my advisor was established, certain patterns, such as his tendency to omit words, got a lot less on my nerves.

---

Today I had a brainwave.  If the speaker's English is that bad, the hosting department should provide an interpreter.

Comment: Maybe - "I'm not very good at understanding *certain* accents"?

Comment: Agreed, "nonstandard" is not a great way to describe it

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've assumed they are a woman? The OP does not gender the person in the question or follow up comments

Comment: @TomJNowell Actually, OP did : see the last line of the third paragraph ("... if she feels the same way."

Comment: @TomJNowell - Thanks, but I'm rolling back because: I'd support your removal of the feminine pronouns if *OP* had not indicated the speaker's gender; "his or her" and "their" both being acceptable ungendered approaches, as the author of the answer, I get to choose.  If you were the copyeditor and I were the journal contributor, you'd get to choose.

Comment: @camden_kid - Can you explain what bothers you about "nonstandard"?

Comment: @neuranna - See above.

Comment: @aparente001 I had the same reaction against "nonstandard." It's not really a big deal, but I think it has a very slight moralizing overtone, since it associates "English I can understand" as "standard" and "English I can't understand" as "nonstandard." The trouble isn't whether it's normal/standard/acceptable/correct/whatever, the trouble is that you, and perhaps some other listeners, can't understand it. NBD, but I'd personally choose another word, especially when it's a touchy subject already as OP notes.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with the suggestion that people with Asperger's don't care whether other people understand them. I think that people with Asperger's are *more* concerned. Neurotypicals just take it for granted that they can phrase things however they want and people will understand them. Saying that people with Asprerger's don't care about being understood is bit like saying that people with cerebral palsy aren't interested in walking.

Comment: @Mike Haskel: But "this accent is less likely to be understood" is exactly what "nonstandard" means. Are we discussing how the OP should inform a speaker that the way the speaker talks makes it difficult for the OP to understand her, or we discussing how the OP should inform a speaker that there are aspects of how she talks that make it harder for *people in general* to understand her? If the latter, then "nonstandard" absolutely is appropriate. If we're going to pretend that the OP's accent is no better than the speaker's, then what is the point of this discussion?

Comment: Use of "nonstandard accent" implies there _is_ a "standard accent". Is there? Which is it? Does most everybody agree on it being the standard? If the answer to any of those questions is "no", and if you care about not offending other people (however irrelevant the offending point might seem), then I agree that alternatives like "certain" or maybe "unfamiliar" are more neutral and so would serve a better purpose in establishing that rapport you very appropriately talked about.

Comment: Just for the record: today, saying that there is such a thing as a "Spanish standard accent" would be fairly offensive to 90% of Spanish speakers. Sure, some accents are understood better by some people, some accents are seen as more "intellectual" etc. -- but to put one above the other would be disrespectful. There is a fair agreement over all Spanish academies, that every Spanish variant is as Spanish as any other. I'm sure any Mexican would be as mad if I told them their accent was "nonstandard" as I would if they told me the same. I can only guess that the same applies to English speakers.

Comment: about your chalk sound: there are combinations of languages which work wonders and are cute. Others are unbereable. On top of this it is often dependent on the speaker. I am French and like to speak English with Germans. I find it clear and understandable. When I hear my compatriotes speaking English (when the vocabulary and grammar are OK but the accent is French) I feel pain for the audience. I can barely understand Chinese and japanese speaking English even though I worked with Asians for years.

Comment: @Acccumulation - I am no expert on Asperger's!  And I only have one data point to go on -- and that data point doesn't even have an official diagnosis.  All I know is that there is someone close to me (well, as close to me as this person's differences permit getting close to people) who drives me nuts, with an obliviousness and lack of interest in the reception part of the communication process.

Comment: Re whether the use of the word "nonstandard" bumps up the potential offensiveness of the approach I suggested in my answer here, see ELU question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/412704/112436.

Comment: @camden_kid - I edited my answer, hopefully it comes across more neutral now.

Answer (score 116):

I think that your plan is based on number of possibly wrong premises. And even if they were mostly right, I doubt such a plan could have any reasonable success. Let's see my reasons.

> I just had a lecture from someone who has been a senior scientist (and has completed a PhD, post-doc) at a hospital for already 15 years.So I'm assuming this person is experienced in giving talks in English.

I've met along the years many senior researchers, even native English speakers, who where definitely not experienced in giving talks, *at all*. If academic researchers are frequently experienced speakers because, at least, they have teaching duties, some researchers from research institutes are really "lab rats" who rarely deliver talks. To give you an example, a few years ago I was attending a poster session in a conference and I told one of the presenters (a native English speaker) that I was surprised that his work had been accepted as poster presentation and not as an oral one. He told me that it was actually accepted as oral presentation, but he asked for a poster one because he doesn't like to deliver talks.

> My impression is that the talk was a waste of time for the two dozen people present.

Talks can be a waste of time for other reasons than terrible language: slides with unreadable results, talk targeted to the wrong audience etc. I certainly attended many talks that could be considered a waste of time for almost anyone in the rooms, and a large fraction of these talks were delivered by allegedly experienced speakers.

> Now I wonder if the speaker is aware of this problem, my guess is no

In my experience among non-native speakers of English, most of the people is well aware of their level of English and of their pronunciation: your guess is likely wrong.

> I feel the need to bring this to the speaker's attention.

Would you feel the same need if the talk were a waste of time for any other reason? And note that preparing readable slides is usually much easier than fixing pronunciation. And are you planning to do such an action for all the useless talks you will attend in your life?

> I feel the need to bring this to the speaker's attention.

As I said, the speaker is probably well aware of this issue, *but can you offer any solution that the speaker is not already aware of?*

Improving pronunciation is not something that can be done easily, especially if one is not keen on languages. The speaker might have had good reasons for not having been able to improve pronunciation more than that. Time and money can be two of them. I don't know how many languages you speak -- you speak more than one, right? I speak Italian, my native language, English and French. My level of English is decent, but my level of French is basic. I cannot make great conversations in French, just short sentences, and sometimes I've been misunderstood (e.g., I once asked for a book called *Rue des Maléfices* and the clerk searched for *Roue des Maléfices*). I'd love to improve my French pronunciation because I spend most of my vacations there but, guess what, I really cannot find the time to do this. Or I'd like to learn German, because I have many German colleagues and I also found some nice physics book in German that I'd like to read without Google translator. Again, I cannot find enough time to learn German even at a basic level.

To conclude, *don't*.

Comment: "Would you feel the same need if the talk were a waste of time for any other reason?" I would. "And are you planning to do such an action for all the useless talks you will attend in your life?" within certain limits, yeah. In the vein of "all that is necessary for evil to succeed is for good people to stand by and do nothing" I feel that people have a moral duty to improve the world around them.

Comment: @Plumpie most of us (Massimo included, I'm sure) try to improve the world around them every day, I feel that's beside the point. The real question is whether your anonymous email will in fact improve the world. I think there's a significant risk that it won't, and may actually do real harm. Lots of experienced people here (who are just as moral and well-meaning as you) are telling you not to send the email. You may want to consider that they have a point, and that they have useful experience that gives them some insight into the psychology of academics with poor English.

Comment: @Plumpie "all that is necessary for evil to succeed is for good people to stand by and do nothing". Do you **really** think that "pronunciation of English that you find difficult to follow" falls into this category? Do you really think that you are the one who can set the world to rights, and have a duty to cast out motes?

Comment: _"Improving pronunciation is not something that can be done easily, especially if one is not keen on languages."_ *I* have one easy thing that works *for me* in English pronunciation, which is to speak slower and focus more on the pronunciation. I always have to balance between not taking too much time to speak and pronouncing correctly. If it turned out my presentations are hard to understand, I would love to know that, so I can speak slower. That would make me be able to speak less, but at least it would be more understandable.

Comment: "Can you offer any solution that the speaker is not already aware of?" Strongly implied by one of OP's comments is *YES*: "slow down". As for leaving this feedback to people who know the speaker well, they are probably tuned in to the accent and so may not be aware that it is a problem.

Comment: On the contrary, improving pronunciation is (in most cases) quite easy. It just takes targeted practice which, in turn, takes a lot of time. Few people have the dedication (but some definitely should consider it). In the case described by OP it sounds like this is definitely in order but it’s not for a stranger to suggest this but rather for a close friends.

Comment: @KonradRudolph assuming you're German (your name), how long did it take you to stop saying **"tyop"** rather than **"dyob"** when trying to pronounce *job*?  And you contradict yourself: You say its easy to  improve pronunciation - QUITE easy, at that! -  but then admit it takes a lot of time ??? Odd. Weird, even.

Comment: @GwenKillerby You’re confusing several things here. For one, slight pronunciation errors, while awful-sounding, don’t generally impede understanding. Moderate foreign accents are completely irrelevant here. Secondly, there’s a difference between something being hard and it being time-consuming. Quantum physics is hard. Folding clothes is time consuming. Also, though irrelevant here, I never used the “typical German” pronunciation of the phonemes “d” and “b” in English and I know few people who do. I don’t know why some people even have difficulty with that. Southern German, maybe?

Comment: @KonradRudolph If something is time consuming and you don't have time, then, yes, it's _hard_ ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano At best in the same vein as preparing presentation slides is hard (less so, in fact: pronunciation can be improved through rote practice; the same isn’t true for other aspects of preparing a presentation), and it is just as integrally part of a good presentation. If it’s just a question of time, the speaker needs to allocate their preparation time differently. We can argue all day long whether that’s “hard” but I’ll say that this isn’t what most people would understand by the word.

Comment: It seems to me that addressing pronunciation in the context of a presentation would be easier in extemporaneous speaking. If you're writing your presentation ahead of time, you can annotate it with notes on how to pronounce the words, and practice going through it very slowly so you can get the pronunciation correct.

Comment: @Plumpie, in contrast to Dan Romik, I'm an experienced and moral person as any other person here, and I think your plan to send an anonymous email is reasonable. Non standard and out of the box, yes (that's IMHO is why people here try to refrain you from doing it). Reasonable and rational, also yes.

Comment: @Dilworth You're way wrong on the motivations and there's nothing reasonable in an _anonymous_ email: just the incapacity of standing behind own's ideas.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, I believe you are wrong. Academia is full anonymous feedback, much more hurtful and cardinal than a somewhat amusing email about one's accent. I'm sure the speaker got many harsh and brutal rejections through anonymous peer review, and she's not going to break because some guy decided to write another anonymous email, peculiar as it sounds. So you see, the academia itself has reserved the right of people not to stand behind their own opinion's and ideas, so that they are protected that way.

Answer (score 47):

**Don't send the email**. Based on my experience, I predict that the anonymous email you are proposing to send almost certainly won't tell the speaker any information she does not already know, only something that she is either in denial about or that she is (for whatever mysterious reasons of human psychology) helpless or unwilling to do anything about. On the other hand, especially due to its anonymous nature, the email is quite likely to come across as hurtful and to cause her negative feelings such as guilt, self-loathing, low self-esteem, depression, etc., that would make her situation worse without leading to any progress towards resolving her accent/language problem.

There is a time and a place to offer people negative feedback that might help them improve, e.g., when such feedback is directly solicited from you or when you are a person whose job it is to offer such feedback. That time and place is not your current situation. So don't.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66663/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-romik-how-to-tell-speakers-that-their-english-is-ter).

Answer (score 16):

Being part of an international research community means, and has always meant, a) learning the lingua franca (so to speak) of the field - some of us are lucky enough to skip this step because we were born into it - and b) learning to understand the wide range of accents that the language will necessarily be spoken in, again much simpler for us native speakers.

If because of auditory disability or "tin ear" you can't understand non-native speakers, then your ability to interact in the international community will be greatly limited.  You can try only talking to locals or using only written communication, but you'd be better off trying to improve your skills through practice.

Comment: Are you seriously blaming OP for not understanding the speaker's poor English (going so far as to insinuate that OP is suffering from a hearing disability and/or insensitivity to foreign cultures)? That is quite rude and inappropriate, and the fact that OP was himself/herself considering doing something similarly rude is no defense. -1

Comment: Well, world english is not a property of UK, US, or other countries where something similar is spoken. It is a new attempt to communicate with less friction. Subsets are important when being intersections, as they lead the way to better understanding. So, easing on what english you might be used to from where you come from, might be the way to go ;-)

Comment: Hi, @DanRomik !  In fact, I am.  Effective communication - especially but not only international communication - requires genuine effort and practice on the part of both communicating parties.  In the case of poor communication, it is much more common for both parties to be at fault.  But practice can help!   Best wishes.

Comment: Although deciphering atrocious English pronunciations is indeed a skill that can be trained (learning the native language of the speaker helps), this post does not answer the question as posted.

Comment: International English is a language with easy spelling and difficult pronunciation. The key to understanding weird accents is that the pronunciation is often based on the spelling. As a grad student, I used to meet many people with nearly unintelligible accents. That doesn't happen as often anymore, as I got used to listening International English. These days I have more trouble with some native accents, if the speakers are not used to dealing with foreigners.

Comment: @dilletant Noone is saying that English is a property of UK, or US. But there's a line which separates a spoken language by a major fraction of language speakers vs one that's not. It's not about any kind of fairness. It's about integration by the means of lingua franca. If a speaker does not meet the "standards bar", he/she needs to change, not the listeners, because the communication protocol is broken on his/her side

Comment: I have to agree that this answer is one perfectly VALID answer.  I spent my formative years in both the US and the UK and became adept at understanding a variety of English Language accents.  Then in a US university I had a calculus TA with a thick French accent - he got massacred by the student reviews many of which said they couldn't understand him.  But I understood every single word he said quite well.  
Conclusion:  it is far easier to learn to understand foreign accents than it is to get rid of a foreign accent (usually impossible for males past puberty).
The onus is on the listener.

Comment: If an entire audience fails to understand a presentation, it is the presenter, and not the audience that has a problem. I can also put in the effort to read poorly written papers, or densely packed slides (and I'm sure everyone has had a lot of practice with that), but that doesn't mean those things are not flawed. I'd also like to see a source for accents being impossible to change @Craig, since I'm (anecdotally) aware of several actors who trained away an accent when needed.

Comment: Certainly I have known people who have excellent ability to change their pronunciation.  But I have gathered over a lifetime hundreds or thousands  of non-native speaker data points in the US, the UK, and abroad in Europe and Asia.  I had a brilliant engineering colleague in his twenties from Korea who lived in the US since he was 13 but sounded like he arrived yesterday.  Yet in Asia I've met many Koreans, Japanese, and Chinese who speak perfect English who have never lived in an English speaking country.

Comment: @mbrig - It doesn't surprise me that you know several actors who trained away an accent (or rather, learned a new accent) - those are people who are by nature language centric.  But university/hospital researchers are not "a priori" language centric - they are chosen for research skills.  So the researcher in question, after 15 years as a senior scientist, has 0% chance of meaningful further improvement in their pronunciation (rounded to units of 10%).  The best they can do is improve the graphical presentation so that it gives a better clue about what is being said, and speak slowly.

Comment: @CraigHicks: First you say that "the onus is on the listener" because the speaker can't do anything about it, then you give specific examples of what the speaker can do to improve it (more-informative visuals, slower speaking). Does this not seem contradictory to you?

Comment: The OPs complaint was pronunciation.  The OP intends to tell the senior researcher that his pronunciation is unintelligible.  My comments about were about presentations in general - things that could improve a native speakers presentation.  So no, it does not seem contradictory.
----- While we're talking about contradictions, if you read my first comment it say this answer is "one perfectly VALID answer".  From the OPs point of the OPs opinion is also perfectly VALID - he listened but couldn't understand anything.  However, the OPs POV is also extremely narrow.

Comment: @ruakh - In general to get that kind of position as a senior researcher requires unique specials skills and creativity.  That talent is rare enough that spoken presentation is takes second precedence - although their written presentation is obviously good enough to pass review, get published, and be read - and that's what counts for researchers.  
I can understand the OPs frustration, but getting fixated on pronunciation, which I don't believe the speaker can change any more after15 years, is pointlessly obsessive.  The OP might try becoming familiar with the speakers papers instead.

Comment: I just cannot wrap around my head how it could be more reasonable to expect to an audience of people from a multitude of backgrounds to be able to understand every single dialect and usage of English than to expect from a (regular) speaker to improve their English so it adheres to one of the multiple understandable standards of using English as well as possible. I have learned multiple languages, but I will never be able to understand every single way that English can be spoken.

Comment: @skymningen - And I can't wrap my head around how "if you want to be part of the international research community, you're going to have to get used to other people's accents" and "communicating technical material is the responsibility of both the speaker and the listener" are now somehow wildly controversial points of view.  So I guess we're both confused.

Answer (score 10):

It's unlikely that a non-native English speaker who often interacts with native speakers is unaware that their English is difficult to understand. Do you speak another language? How would you feel if someone sent you an anonymous email informing you that you were completely incomprehensible? Especially if you already knew that people often had trouble understanding you?

On the other hand, you are correct about communication skills. Nonetheless, it's possible for someone to communicate well during a lecture or presentation despite having a difficult accent or weak skills in the target language. You might try offering feedback about how they could improve their presentation *given* their current language skills, but only if you know that such feedback would be constructive and welcome.

Comment: "Do you speak another language? How would you feel if someone sent you an anonymous email informing you that you were completely incomprehensible? " I'd feel pretty motivated to make a change. "Especially if you already knew that people often had trouble understanding you?" I'm 95% sure she's not aware. If you're talking in a language you know you're bad in, would you talk really fast and clearly show no effort? Because usually when people try hard to speak correctly you can see they're making an effort.

Comment: @Plumpie It's more likely that she's perfectly aware but she has no intention of doing anything about it because she feels that her rank and expertise entitle her to that. Either way, it's safe to say that your anonymous "feedback" is not going to be well received.

Comment: @Plumpie I suspect that most people would feel offended and somewhat intimidated to receive anonymous criticism. At the very least, it looks _creepy_.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning If she's perfectly aware that she can't communicate properly, and is continuing to conduct lectures, then she is failing to do her job properly, and is letting down people (attendees) who depend on her. If she feels her rank and expertise means that she doesn't need to improve her communication, then she should transfer to a job that doesn't require communicating. I agree on the point that any feedback should not be anonymous.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with you that the speaker should be told. Contrary to other aspects of a talk (slides clarity, order, etc..) which are somewhat optional and left to the speaker's interest in making a good talk, intelligibility of the speech is a minimum requirement. Not taking care of this is probably hurting them badly.

Last time I attended in a very similar situation one of the more senior speakers approached the unintelligible speaker and flat out told them : "Do you know it's very hard to understand you when you speak"?. I was there and made a little joke to lighten up the comment and we walked away but the speaker most likely got the message.

So, there's one way. If you do not have the seniority required to give unrequested advices in person tho, your suggestion seems fine to me. Send an anonymous email explaining that you had a very hard time understanding the talk. Just make sure you are passing out the right message, that you are trying to make them aware of what you felt was a big issue making communication difficult and not shaming them for it.

As to what  people have said in other answers :

1) the speaker might be aware of the issue, but not of its severity. This might give them the push they need to act on it. 
2) there's plenty of free and little time consuming ways of improving pronunciation (movies, pre practicing talks, YouTube videos, slowing down when speaking ) 
3) I don't think you are 'shaming' the , no one asks for British English in academia and accents are usually never questioned..as long as they can reasonably be understood

Comment: As I pointed out on someone else's answer: the speaker mentioned by the OP is female

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice when reading from phone. Fixed.

Comment: I do not assume bad faith. The speaker might well be aware and have a thousand reasons for not being able to tackle this. I just think a polite 
 and non-snarky email need not offend and might prove motivational and informative.

As a foreigner English language speaker in Academia I do believe this is a problem. I've been to several seminars where the speaker was almost unintelligible. 

I have not followed the rest of the discussion on comments, so I don't speculate on the author of the question either.

Comment: +1 You hit the nail on the head with "reasonably understood". There's nothing wrong with a foreign accent as long as they're understandable. I've heard Scottish people who speak English with such a thick accent that they're almost impossible to understand, and that's their native language! (Besides which, personally I'd be happy if someone told me my attempts at foreign languages weren't very good if they were prepared to tell me what words I need to get better at pronouncing.)

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to the majority of opinions here, as a non-native speaker, I would say that an anonymous email would be helpful. It won't give you any brownie points, and may hurt the speaker's feeling, but it will be helpful to the person regardless. **In general, we already give one another too few honest feedbacks out of politeness** -- anything in the other direction would be a valuable change.

The most popular answer here asks: "Would you give the feedback if it were about any issue other than English?" I concede that it's not the norm to do so, but it doesn't mean that such a feedback wouldn't be helpful. Indeed, my advisor gives me feedback on the structure of my talk, its graphs, and its typos -- why not my English as well? (In fact, he does comment on when I need to slow down or fix a grammatical mistake).

The speaker may be aware that he has an issue with language, but he may not realize *the extent* of the problem. There's a chance that the feedback may help, and it sure can't hurt, so why not?

Granted, since you do not play the advisor role to the speaker, I would absolutely advise against a direct conversation. Most likely, it'll make the speaker feel resentful towards you, no matter how helpful your advice is. (Such is regrettably human nature). But an anonymous email would work perfectly well.

Comment: As an advisor, I certainly give feedback to my students on their presentations: I discuss structure, graphics, text _and_ English. But they are my students and it's my role to provide guidance to them (and frequently it's not pain-free for them), but I wouldn't bring this up to someone whose background I don't know.

Comment: Your advisor gives you feedback because he is your **advisor**. The OP seems to be in a completely different relationship to the speaker who is the subject of his/her post, and this makes **all** the difference to whether his/her actions are either appropriate or helpful

Comment: It's absolutely not OP's job or duty to offer feedback. It's also not advisable from an interpersonal skill standpoint to offer feedback since there's a decent chance of the speaker getting offended. But if the OP **wants** to give feedback via an **anonymous** email, it won't hurt the OP and have a decent chance to help the speaker.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I absolutely agree that, as a rule, advisors offer these kinds of feedbacks and strangers don't. I'd like to probe further why do we follow this rule? I find that by not giving feedback as often, we all rob one another of opportunities for improving. There's the legitimate concern of people reacting poorly to unprompted feedback -- hence my suggestion of an **anonymous** email.

Comment: "But if the OP wants to give feedback via an anonymous email, it won't hurt the OP and have a decent chance to help the speaker" - I disagree with the second part, and the only reason the first part might be true is that the recipient won't know who sent them this presumptuous and unsolicited commentary

Comment: Why do people who want to offer anonymous feedback think that they are actually in the right?

Comment: The fact is that not just OP, but multiple people at the talk find it difficult to understand the speaker. The speaker may not know this fact, hence by just mentioning this fact alone, the OP is potentially being helpful. The OP does not have to offer other advice regarding how to improve the pronunciation, which I admit is much less clearly right or wrong.

Comment: @Heisenberg "There's the legitimate concern of people reacting poorly to unprompted feedback" but that is only good for the OP, not anyone else, except for the 2 other people HE talked to. So it's selfish, and therefor, BAD. Also, you're assuming vindictiveness on the speakers part. Why?

Comment: Anonymous feedback is for students fearing repercussions and trolls. If you are going to say something "potentially sensitive", stand behind it, specially if the recipient is not your boss.

Comment: @GwenKillerby The "anonymous email" strategy protects the interest of OP while does not hurt anyone else. I'm not sure I see how this is "bad". I assume vindictiveness from on the speaker's part because accent is a touchy topic, which *may* cause *some* people to react poorly with a non-trivial likelihood. I find the amount of emotion and discussion on this thread as evidence of how strongly people feel about the topic.

Comment: Actually, lying politely to the speaker by denying her the knowledge that her lecture skills must improve is more "selfish" than sending an anon email. I think it is a legitimate action.

Answer (score 9):

**No,** unless you are explicitly asked. You could simply look arrogant, the speaker could hate you, and the speaker's supporters could also feel resentful. Your reputation could suffer, or at least I don't see how it would grow. Moreover, criticizing the person is *not your job*, and anonymous feedback takes your time.

If you think you lost time while listening because of the accent, you might bring this to the attention to the host of the person or to the session chair. It's the job of the session chair, the host, the mentor, or the supervisor to provide criticism and feedback to the speaker. If you really wish to, talk to these folks personally and utmost politely; don't leave any written trail.

Answer (score 6):

If your advice is not successfully actionable in the short-term, it may not be considered that constructive by the recipient.

**So no, do not send her that feedback.**

That being said, ask the organizers of the event (or the faculty in charge) to provide transcripts of the talk in advance the next time around, especially if there is any doubt about the ability of their speakers to speak English clearly.

Do not ask for the slides. The slides are designed to be incomplete (and for good reasons). What you must ask for is the transcript. And by transcript, I do not mean that the speaker should read her own transcript while giving her presentation. Reading a script, while making it sound natural, is extremely difficult.

Ideally, the speaker's own notes (the one she has on the podium) should only of consist of a few keywords and key topics that the speaker doesn't want to forget to mention during her lecture. It should not contain full sentences, let alone paragraphs. So in that sense, the lecture shouldn't match the transcript perfectly. But even when it doesn't match the lecture perfectly, a transcript for a speaker, members of the audience do not understand, can still be very useful.

Providing a transcript in advance may not be what you're used to in your academic field, but it is possible and it's actually a pretty standard practice if someone does a presentation in front of journalists (even when the speaker is a native English speaker). For journalists, supplying a transcript in advance helps catch mistakes before they get reprinted, whether the speaker makes the mistake when speaking or whether the journalist makes the mistake when quoting the spoken words of the speaker.

From the point of view of the organizers, that will require pre-screening potential speakers, by previewing previous talks, or if that's not possible, by talking to the potential speakers directly.  This is also a standard practice in some Academic circles, whether the screening process is made obvious or not.

Furthermore, as a non-native English speaker myself with a pretty strong French accent, I'm suggesting that whoever does that pre-screening is a non-native English colleague with an obvious accent himself/herself.

And instead of simply rejecting a talk because the speaker has too strong of an accent, a good pre-screener should still encourage the speaker to still speak at the event, but to supply a transcript in advance at the very least (in addition to any tentative improvement to his accent or delivery), and if that transcript is not possible by a specific deadline, to reject that talk for that event.

Comment: "ask the organizers of the event (or the faculty in charge) to provide transcripts of the talk in advance the next time around" Is this something that happens? Surely that would be difficult or impossible to provide. Personally, I deliberately don't write down a script of what I'm going to say in a talk, and even if I did, I doubt I would stick to it very closely. I don't think I'm unusual in that regard.

Comment: How is it not actionable? something not actionable would be 'you suck' whereas providing a specific point that can be improved provides a clear path forward.

Comment: Asking for a transcript seems like a good idea, but lying about a disability is not.

Comment: "What you must ask for [in advance] is the transcript." The _what_? Talks (with the exception of some fields) aren't delivered from a script. There is no stenographer. There is no transcript.

Comment: user2390246, I agree that most people wouldn't follow a script closely, but still a script would still be useful if your spoken English is not understood by your audience. @David Richerby, I wasn't lying, nor I was suggesting lying. People do vary in abilities in understanding foreign sounds. It's like someone who is near-sighted, or far-sighted, or has butterflies appearing in their vision. One doesn't need to be legally blind to politely ask for an accommodation for the next time around, especially if that accommodation is the only way you'll be able to follow what's going on.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk If you're near- or far- sighted, you're wearing glasses or contacts unless your vision problem is at the level of a recognised disability. I'm having difficulty seeing "I'm not good at understanding foreign accents" as any kind of recognised disability. It doesn't seem much different from putting in a request along the lines of, "I'm not very good at math so please ask all your speakers to go real slow during the mathy parts of their talks."

Comment: Certainly, the OP's advice is actionable and helpful. The speaker must make effort to improve her English, just like she and all of us make effort to improve our lectures, content, form, exposition skills, strategy etc.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, If math is not a basic requirement in that specific field, then yes, such a request may be appropriate. The same goes for foreign languages. Some fields require that you know specific languages and knowing a specific language actually helps you understand a particular accent. But if that language is not a particular basic requirement of your field, then you would have a good reason to ask for a written transcript in advance. In any case, I've amended my original answer considerably. I hope that my amended answer gets a better reception.

Comment: Requesting a transcript is still completely infeasible.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Then, let's just agree to disagree on that one.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the commenters that as a listener to the presentation you should probably avoid commenting on the lecturer's clarity (eg because of poor English) unless you are in very friendly and constructive terms with her.

However, I think you could still politely tell her that the presentation was interesting but you couldn't follow perfectly given the poor sound/background noise, and so you would like to receive a copy of the slideset. Then you could suggest to make the slides more self-explanatory.

Your question is more interesting however from the viewpoint of moderators or scientific committee member. In such a case, they have the explicit responsibility to the audience that lectures are clear and understandable. Otherwise, what would be the point of inviting people to lecture at all? Most importantly, a genuinely constructive feedback will be important for the lecturer himself, to avoid future embarassments.

A simple suggestion for anyone with language difficulties is to create/modify a slideset by adding as many self-explanatory phrases as possible. This creates redundancies for a competent lecturer, but saves a poor one. Eventually, such a slideset will only leave the room for poor pronunciation, but all key messages will be firmly delivered.

Answer (score 1):

Some people either make no effort, or have strong difficulties polishing their strong accent. It might depend on the original language. For the English/American native, some people with Roman background language (as I do) fall in this category.

The state of energy of the person can play a role too: when one is sick, stressed or tired, efforts can be difficult. When I give a lecture in English, I notice that after one hour my natural accent begins to show up.

I agree that university  authorities are more responsible for the add value of a lecture. Yet, if you tell them, the impact on how they will translate the issue to the lecturer might be far different, from not taking care to harsher remarks.

As your motivation stands between these two extreme options, I would avoid a written comment, perhaps even more with an anonymous email. But that might be a cultural thing; I'd prefer a direct talk, face to face if possible, in the line of your planned email, for instance to check whether the problem is the same in individual talk: thank the person, ask for the slides, pointing that due to accent-related misunderstandings, you might have lost key aspects of the talk.

Answer (score 1):

People often resent unsolicited feedback because the person giving it doesn't recognize that truly empathetic feedback requires effort on the part of the person giving it. Constructive feedback must give a path forward for the person to correct the problem.

I would try this strategy: Purchase [Mastering the American Accent](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1438008104) for this person, and make a nice inscription:

> I truly enjoyed your recent presentation, and I felt disheartened that I was unable to understand much of it. Your research is relevant to mine, and fundamentally important, so I was hoping we could find a way to improve communication. I am available any time to help you with American pronunciation and accent-if you so desire.

Sign it with your real name.

If in fact you do not care about learning from this person, then leave the issue alone.

Answer (score -4):

**Yes, you might want to send the email**. I think it will have good and productive effect overall, and help the speaker further in her career a lot. Such criticism, though very unpleasant and even hurtful to hear at first, opens the opportunity to self-improvement. 
Your act thus shows that you do care for the speaker. Much more than a person who simply wants to minimize his or her in-comfort, shy away from confrontation and leave the speaker alone and deserted without knowing that secretly the community ignores and disdain her.

As for the fact that the email is anonymous, something that have alerted many commenters here, I disagree with the overall opinion. Academia is full of anonymous feedback, most of which has the potential to be much more hurtful and cardinal than a somewhat amusing email about one's accent. I'm sure the speaker got many harsh and brutal rejections through anonymous peer review, throughout her career, and she's not going to break down because some guy decided to write an anonymous email, peculiar as it sounds. Indeed, academia itself has reserved the right for people "not to stand behind their own opinions" and ideas, so that they feel protected to speak freely, through endless forms of anonymous feedback (reviews and student's feedback, to name a few).

Comment: Academia is full of _solicited_ anonymous feedback. Anonymous,  unsolicited, critical emails feel threatening and aggressive. Why does the email have to be anonymous at all?

Comment: @DavidRicherby, actually almost none of the anonymous feedback in the academia is solicited by the person the feedback is about. When students give anonymous feedback in my classes, I'm not soliciting this. It's an administrator decision. The same with other feedback. So your point is moot. Academia is full of anonymous feedback solicited mostly by third parties who wish to regulate and even punish you based on the feedback. A rejection by a journal or a sanction against you due to a negative feedback is more "aggressive" than an email about accent that has nor repercussions.

Comment: When you give a class, you know that the admins will be soliciting anonymous feedback from the students; depending on institutional policies, it might even be you who hands out the forms and asks the students to fill them in. When you submit a paper, you know the editors will be soliciting feedback and passing it to you anonymously. All of this is solicited by someone and expected by the person who receives the feedback. So, no, my point isn't remotely moot. And I've never heard of an "aggressive" rejection letter.

Comment: No. The fact that you are aware that someone forces you to accept anonymous feedback, in order for you to keep your job, puts the feedback you get as a lecturer precisely in the same ethical status as an anonymous email about one's accent. If at all, students feedback is more daunting as it has consequence on your job security. Also, every rejection is a form of an aggressive action, by definition. And if you didn't get an aggressively written review, well, then I'd say you're lucky.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no moral equivalency _whatsoever_ between allowing students and peer reviewers to make anonymous feedback and sending anonymous nastygrams about somebody's accent. Note, in particular, that student feedback is anonymous to prevent retribution (the teacher is in a direct position of power over their students) and peer review is only anonymous to the ultimate recipient but the editor knows exactly who the reviewers are. Individual reviews might, unfortunately, be aggressive but the editor's decision is not. If your employer is aggressive in handling feedback on your...

Comment: ... classes, that is unacceptable and you should complain about it. (Anonymously, if necessary, because, again, you are complaining to somebody with direct power over you and may wish to avoid retribution.)

Comment: No, I disagree. There is a very clear ethical equivalence (and I'm being conservative here in your favor), between job-detrimental anonymous feedback solicited by administrators, or editors, and a naïve, authentic, and clumsy anonymous email of a listener that have no consequence on the career of the speaker. Notice that usually the reviewer is kept anonymous from the authors although they are by no means under the author's direct position of power. A rejection is an act of aggression, by definition, and it causes to all of us hurt and harsh feelings. That is the reality.

Comment: I believe that you can rationalize every norm, the way you do, so that it *sounds* as if it is actually devoid of any negative ethical consequences. But the reality is that society is structured and organized following quite aggressive rules.

Comment: Please look up "aggression" in a dictionary and tell me which part of saying "No, we won't publish your paper" meets that definition. Also, note that your job in no way depends on any individual piece of student feedback.

Comment: You seem not to understand the term "aggression". This concept refers to many different kinds of hostile and forceful actions against a person. For example, executing criminals is a kind of aggression some countries have in their power. The act of executing a person is an aggressive act irrespective of the procedure and moral justification given to this act. Same, though much lesser in measure of aggresivity, goes to firing someone, or rejecting one's paper. Both are actions acutely going against essential interests of a person, causing them pain and suffering. Irrespective of the reasons

Comment: I'm sorry but there's no equivalency between executing somebody and rejecting their paper.

Comment: There's no equivalency. That's an analogy. Both are legal and legitimate actions, in the spectrum of aggressive actions. One is on the extreme end of the spectrum and the other is hurtful, and damaging but not as extreme. Still, both damage the interest of the individual in order to serve a larger goal. The first reprehesion and deterrence of criminals in order to provide social order, the other to distribute academic capital and resources based on merit.